# Create generic TypeScript function that will assign a value to object property

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

I want to create a simple function that will take **key** of a specific object and **value** for the respective key and assign the new value to the object. Something like this:

```
interface MyObject {
    key1: string
    key2: number
}

const object: MyObject = {
    key1: 'abc',
    key2: 100
}

const updateObjectProperty = (key: keyof MyObject, value: MyObject[keyof MyObject]) => {
    object[key] = value
}
```

But in this case - it's not working. TypeScript complier shows an error:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

I feel like maybe some generics could potentially resolve the problem here, but I'm struggling to figure out how.

Answer (score 3):

If you tie the parameters together using a generic type parameter, it will compile:

```
const updateObjectProperty = <K extends  keyof MyObject>(key: K, value: MyObject[K]) => {
    object[key] = value
}

updateObjectProperty("key1", "") //ok
updateObjectProperty("key2", "") // err
updateObjectProperty("key2", 2) // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwFgAoZK5AawnQEYAuZAZzClAHMLrb6ATCxABXALbZoFAL4UKCAPYh2yBXgJgWGHPkLIAvCV7U6jFgHI42BOYA0xqqaHIGABlcy55RcqIiADgAmcJA6GgAKUAr+0GDoBsgAPADSyBAAHpAggayO9AowaFjqhAB8ABSmLMm2yABucAA2IhBaxbpgANrJALoAlAalRpTUah2dpj0JDc0QnuQUAcGhJWCR0bHo5QBEpgzbtdvbAwD0Jwo0i0EhEGGE6zFQcTtOB8hHpydpUFBXy7erB6bF6CN4CT6qGhAA)

The reason your version does not work is that you could pass in uncorrelated key and value:

```
updateObjectProperty("key2", "") // key2 now has a string
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwFgAoZK5AawnQEYAuZAZzClAHMLrb6ATCxABXALbZoFAL4UKCAPYh2yBXgJgWGHPkLIAvCV7U6jFgHI42BOYA0xqqaHIGABlcy55RcqIiADgAmcJA6GgAKUAr+0GDoBsgAFKYspgowaFjqhLbIAG5wADYiEFpZumAA2mkZ2tlgALoAlAYAfEaU1GoV1fQNCQXFEJ7kAcGh9ZHRseiJAEROc7lzcy0A9Gv86ALIIAoA7sgAFnCsyHBsHNwUQA)

Now our new version is not 100% safe either, you could call it with `key` union, but that is less common:

```
let k: keyof MyObject = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "key1" : "key2"
let v: MyObject[keyof MyObject] = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 0 : "key2"

updateObjectProperty(k, v); // fails when key and value are mssmatched
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwFgAoZK5AawnQEYAuZAZzClAHMLrb6ATCxABXALbZoFAL4UKCAPYh2yBXgJgWGHPkLIAvCV7U6jFgHI42BOYA0xqqaHIGABlcy55MOgAOKADU4ABsRCABJcGhWDWAlACF0AGl6AFUQOJAAHgAVWyoclPRkCAAPSBAAE1Z+dAUYZByAPgMjSmQAbQAFZFBGooBdFgAKGhYc7oGASn0mgDcFYEqZTsL6AZLyiCqa4dGWUBhoZHCZ+cXKqeQAfhPkYQg5qXJ5JRURX0q4SB0NLqgFP4oD5WlkkpsKtVHPR6mgsOpCE1RvQWEl8nMQmEtPDdGAOklpgYWmR2lQ1LiOqYNoYMaEIJ4XuRghAiGNarDtAiiIZUN8ABYAOigcCqCjEwyuLVcAoArDdkAAiUwMBX3RVOBUUZlEObY36ESkwhqc3HUtD8oUiypiiXIKWy+WuNVKwSaxkfL4-Ln-QHQHyjdFTADcyAA9KH4MBgjUAO587a1ZBW5C0sJJqAoMSsVhib4IePLchAA)

You could do the same thing that TS does, and type value as an intersection of possible property values, and this will catch this loophole too, but that would require an assertion in the implementation again:

```
type ValueIntersectionByKeyUnion<T,  TKey extends keyof T> = {
  [P in TKey]: (k: T[P])=>void
} [TKey] extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

const updateObjectProperty = <K extends  keyof MyObject>(key: K, value: ValueIntersectionByKeyUnion<MyObject, K>) => {
    object[key] = value as MyObject[K];
}

let k: keyof MyObject = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "key1" : "key2"
let v: MyObject[keyof MyObject] = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 0 : "key2"

updateObjectProperty(k, v); //err

updateObjectProperty("key1", "") //ok
updateObjectProperty("key2", "") // err
updateObjectProperty("key2", 2) // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-GAaX253uwJa-360A)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are not specifying a relationship between `key` and `value`. You are saying that `key` can be any property in `MyObj` and that `value` can be the type of any of that object's properties.

If you define a generic `T` as `keyof MyObject` and use that to define both parameters, you will get the behavior you are looking for.

[See a live example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMZAbwChkLkBrCdARgC5kBnMKUAc3MpvQCYmIAK4BbbNFIBfUqQQB7EK2Ry8BMEww58hZAF4S3Cr0bIA5HGwJTAGkPVaA5HQAMzqTJhCQhYAuRCABwATOEgtNQAFKDkA6DB0AB4AFWQIAA9IECDme3Q5GDQsVUIAPgAKXiYk62QANzgAGyEIDSLtMABtJIBdAEoDSmVizt5uvTrG5oBudxlAkLDhqJi49DLTYxtkACI6bd6Z+dCIcMJl2Kh49c2augPSI8X289Xrhy3d-cPg49OwF8uaw271u90eJyW0QuV2B6AAzFs7jMgA)

```
function updateObjectProperty<T extends keyof MyObject>(key: T, value: MyObject[T]) {
    object[key] = value;
}
```

Notice the squigglies showing you invalid parameters passed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
const updateObjectProperty = <T extends keyof MyObject>(key: T, value: MyObject[T]) => {
    object[key] = value
}
```